# dual pane screen and windows snap

Tags: windows-7

I like to run two windows side by side- either two web browser windows or a code editor and a browser.

How do I snap these two together. The desired effect is if F minimise them, they both get minimised and if click on one to return to it- they both go back to side by side

Answer (score 0):

There's no way (that I'm aware of) to tether a window to another and minimize/maximize them with a single click. But there are quick, convenient workarounds to this. Start with snap-fit windows: a browser and an editor side by side. You can use the following shortcuts:

<kbd>Win</kbd> is the Windows button

1. To minimize both windows simultaneously, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
2. To maximize both windows really quickly, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> in succession. This is assuming your browser and editor windows are the first and second windows shown in your taskbar as below
   [image]

Rather than figure out a way to tinker around with Windows settings/API, it makes much more sense to become familiar with all of Windows 7's [keyboard shortcuts](http://lifehacker.com/5390086/the-master-list-of-new-windows-7-shortcuts).

A quick way to snap-fit *any* window (regardless of size, position) is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+left arrow for a left snap-fit and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+right arrow to push it to the right. I had no idea about many of these shortcuts, hope they help